# How to set RSpec time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm testing with RSpec and rspec-rails 2.10.

I've set Rails timezone as UTC at environment.rb, but RSpec time zone becomes my local timezone, Tokyo.

I've wrote Time.zone setteing at environments/test.rb and spec_helper.rb but didin't fixed.

How to set RSpec time zone?

Comment: Could you please post a code? "RSpec time zone" is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @TanzeebKhalili, The link you posted is a highcharts javascript fiddle, not related to Rspec, Timezones, or ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is another point.
I wrote a method which adjust time zone offset, and the method changes the Rails time zone.
Here is the code.

```
class WeeklyEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
    def adjust_time_zone_offset
        Time.zone = timezone # => This is the problem. Rails Time.zone changes to timezone.
        time_zone_offset = Time.zone.utc_offset # => 32400 JST offset 9 hours in seconds.
        self.start_date_time  = (start_date_time - time_zone_offset).in_time_zone('UTC')
    end
 end

 japanese_event = WeeklyEvent.find(1)
 p japanese_event.start_date_time  #=> Sun, 01 Jan 2012 09:00:00 JST +09:00
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `Time.zone.now` instead of `Time.now`.

Comment: the question is about how to change the time zone